# What is the meaning of this Excel formula?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

```
=Indirect("D"&H4+1)
```

Can anyone explain what this formula does in an Excel sheet?

Answer (score 3):

`H4` will have a row number

`H4+1` will add one to that number

`"D"&H4+1` will create a string that looks like a valid cell address.

`Indirect("D"&H4+1)` turns that string into an actual valid cell address and will return the value in that cell.

But note that INDIRECT is Volatile and should be avoided when possible.  Use INDEX instead:

```
=INDEX(D:D,H4+1)
```

Which does the same without the volatility.